# iOS: +[NSString stringWithUTF8String] producing unpredictable results?

Tags: ios, utf-8

I'm retrieving some UTF8-encoded HTML from a server. (In this particular case, I can tell that every time I make a request, I'm getting 763 bytes back.)

I then pass these bytes to +[NSString stringWithUTF8String], and about 90% of the time, I get a resulting string that looks exactly like the HTML in my file on the server. 10% of the time, I get nil.

I have utterly no reason why this would be inconsistent. The bytes being read from the server by NSURLConnection are identical every time.

Anyone have any ideas? Here is the code:

```
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url] queue:customTableOperationQueue
            completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse* response, NSData* data, NSError* error)
            {
                if (! error)
                {
                    NSString* newTableHTML = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:data.bytes];
                    NSLog(@"data.length = %d, newTableHTML.length = %d", data.length, newTableHTML.length);
                    self.tableHTML = newTableHTML;
                }
                else
                {
                    self.tableHTML = nil;
                    self.errorMessage = error.localizedDescription;
                }
            }
        ];
```

Comment: How are you ensuring the data is NUL-terminated? From this code it looks like 90% of the time you're lucky that there's a NUL at the right spot, and the other 10% of the time you're lucky that your program doesn't crash.

Comment: For the case that you get nil: what's data.length and can you dump data.bytes?

Comment: @ughoavgfhw Yes, that was the problem. And I sort of thought that might be the problem, but I was looking for a call that would let me pass in the length and they'd all been deprecated. Turns out, -[NSString initWithData:encoding:] is how you accomplish that.

Comment: @Greg You could also use the `initWithBytes:length:encoding:` method, but it is better to pass the data directly and let the string handle it.